# Как сделать, чтобы DIV подстраивался под ширину контента?

Tags: css

Вопрос в следующем: как сделать так, чтобы DIV, в котором написан текст, подстраивался по ширине под ширину текста, а не был шириной 100%?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавьте в стили блока `display:inline-block` или `display:inline`.

Пример:

```
<div style="display:inline-block;background:#f00">text</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает :)

Comment: Тут надо отметить, что после добавления подобных стилей блок перестает быть блоком.

Comment: @karmadro4, я думаю, это более чем очевидно.

Comment: Для тех кто в танке: чем тогда становиться блок?

Comment: @zenith, если дословно, "внутрестрочным блоком"

Comment: ... что приводит к выводу, что блоки не были нужны изначально.

Comment: @karmadro4, вынужден не согласиться. Блок не только остается блоком, но еще и приобретает свойства строчных элементов. К элементу применимы и ряд свойств принадлежащих только блоку и ряд свойств применимых к строчным элементам.